# How to distinguish between built-in and user-defined functions in Vim syntax highlighting for C?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm currently using the following code in my `c.vim` to highlight function names in C:

```
syn match cUserFunction "\<\h\w*\>\(\s\|\n\)*("me=e-1 contains=cParen,cCppParen

hi def link cUserFunction Function
```

This code successfully highlights all function names, but it doesn’t distinguish between built-in and user-defined functions. I would like to have user-defined functions highlighted in one group (e.g., cUserFunction) and built-in functions highlighted in a different group (e.g., cBuiltinFunction).

Is there a way to achieve this in Vim for C and C++ codes? Any help would be appreciated :)

PS: I took the code from this [wonderful repo!](https://github.com/bfrg/vim-cpp-modern)

Comment: I think that's practically impossible.  Technically you could use a list of all built-in functions to feed into a highlight group, but that'd be insanity.  I strongly suggest you don't waste time in syntactic sugar.  Rather spend that time on learning the editing features in Vim.

Comment: Library functions don't have reserved names in C and C++. You can roll your own `memcpy`. Would that be a user-defined function (you wrote it yourself) or a built-in (according to the signature)? In C++, you could match functions prefixed with `std::` but that's a shaky heuristic at best. IMHO, any of LSP, ctags, cscope or static code checkers should give a bigger productivity boost than nicer syntax highlighting.